# How to subtract from a smaller number in binary?

Tags: binary

I have two numbers. The negative one is translated using 2's complement.

```
a = 160 = A0 = 1010 0000
b = -28 = E4 = 1110 0100
```

And I have to perform the following operation `a - b`. I use borrowing up to the very last bit, but then I have a situation like.

```
      0 1
    - 1 1
      ---
      ? 0
```

Should I borrow from something imaginary? In decimal `1 - 3 = -2`, so the answer is `BC`, but how do you reason about the negative `2` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing 2's complement calculation, both numbers are 2's complement, so `A0` is equal to decimal `-96` and not `160`.

`160` is not representable in 8bit 2's complement. I will use 9bit 2's complement here.

`a - b` where `a=160` and `b=-28` is equal to `160 + 28`. Is that what you want?

```
  0 1010 0000
+ 0 0001 1100
-------------
  0 1011 1100
```

or do you want to calculate `160 - 28`? this is equal to `160 + (-28)`

```
  0 1010 0000
+ 1 1110 0100
-------------
 10 1000 0100
```

we can ignore the left 1, because we are doing 9bit 2's complement calculation. So the result is `0 1000 0100` which is `132`.

This is the advantage of the 2's complement, you don't have to do a subtraction, you can add the 2's complement of the number instead of subtract it.

8bit 2's complement with the original binaries:

```
  1010 0000
+ 1110 0100
  ---------
 11000 0100
```

the result is `1000 0100` which is `-124` (-96 - 28).

Comment: Why would we want the 8 bit 2's complement? That's not the right answer of  160-28 right?

Comment: @Jwan622 we do not want to use the 8 bit 2's complement here, because 160 is not representable in 8bit 2's complement. Therefore using the (wrong) 8bit 2's complement value of 160 (which is really -96) will give a wrong result.